# How to detect if an input field is still being edited when exiting a Form?

Tags: codenameone

In my app, I use actionListeners to capture when a user has input data and then update the object. However, I've noticed that this doesn't work if the user exits the Form (previousForm.showBack()) while still editing the TextArea, or without clicking Done in the Picker. This is actually quite a common use case since the user enters data and leaves the Form directly, meaning that data is often lost.

Is there a way to handle this, e.g. detect if a field is still being edited and 'force' the update as the user exits the Form? Ideally, it should simply trigger the usual actionListener to avoid duplicating the code.

I've noticed Form.getCurrentInputDevice() but don't understand its purpose, so not sure if that's could be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.addDataChangedListener()` and save the data to Preferences too.
For example,

```
nameTextField.addDataChangedListener((evt1, evt2)->{
     if(nameTextField.getText().trim().length()>0){
         Preferences.set("name", nameTextField.getText().trim());
     }
});
```

Then, if you go back and come back to this form, you just retrieve the data in
`String savedNameInput = Preferences.get("name", "");`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to extract this to a test case but this works for me. This shouldn't be required and should be seamless:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
Button gotoFormB = new Button("Go To B");
Label text = new Label(" ");
hi.add(gotoFormB);
hi.add(text);
hi.show();

gotoFormB.addActionListener(e -> {
    Form formB  = new Form("Form B", BoxLayout.y());
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    formB.add(tf);
    tf.addActionListener(ee -> text.setText(tf.getText()));
    formB.getToolbar().setBackCommand("Back", ee -> {
        hi.showBack();
    });
    formB.show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I confirm it works for TextField. But it does not seem to work for Pickers (lightweight) - if the picker is open and a date is shown and I then leave the screen, the picker's actionListener is not triggered and the value is lost. Should I report a bug on this? On iOS, I confirm it works for native pickers, since it seems that iOS itself prevents leaving a screen when a one is open.

Comment: How do you leave the picker?

Comment: I simply leave the Picker open and click back. It shows by adding this code to you test above: Picker p = new Picker();
p.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
p.addActionListener(ee -> text.setText(p.getDate().toString()));
formB.add(p); Click the Picker, set a date, leave it open and click Back directly.

Comment: If you click outside of a picker you're effectively canceling it so I'd say that's correct behavior.

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand that the behavior in the situation I described is not the same for TextField and Picker (having the same would of course be ideal for simplicity's sake). In any case, is there a way to intercept  the Picker cancellation to not lose the entered date? Would you consider extending the current behavior to trigger the ActionListener, even for a cancellation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that would be so simple. As far as the picker is concerned it's still showing when you go back. It wasn't even canceled since it's in an interaction dialog. So I'm not sure if there's a proper event we can use.

Comment: Would it make sense to replicate the behavior seen on iOS: that the native picker blocks the UI until you select either OK or Cancel? Or add an option to the light picker that clicking outside the picker can be interpreted as accepting the value instead of implicit Cancel?

Comment: Right now it's an interaction dialog. I guess it could be made into a dialog without dispose when clicked outside. That might have other implications though such as tab order issues etc. You can file an RFE and ask for it but I'm not sure when we'll get around to it. This is the codehttps://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.java#L628 notice it's a bit convoluted.